# numpy.linspace - bad labels on the X axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have this small plotting program.
But when I run it I notice the labels on the X axis are incorrect.
They go from 0 to 5000 while actually I have the interval `[-1.5, 1.5]`

1... How can I fix that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 5000)
y1 = np.tan(x) * np.arctan(x)
y2 = x * x

plt.plot(y1)
plt.plot(y2)

plt.show()
```

2... Also, if I change the linspace to call
`x = np.linspace(-mt.pi/2.0 + 1/(10**6), mt.pi/2.0 - 1/(10**6), 5000)`

I get an even stranger and really incorrect plot.
Something gets messed up completely.
Why? I want to plot these 2 functions in the range `(-pi/2, pi/2)`
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 5000)
y1 = np.tan(x) * np.arctan(x)
y2 = x * x
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

Now `x` axis values are is between -1.5 and 1.5.

Regarding strange plot in second case just notice that:

`np.tan(-1.5)`
-14.101419947171719

and:

`np.tan(-mt.pi/2.0)`
-1.633123935319537e+16

which is much much bigger.

Comment: Ah... so it's that simple, thanks... What about my 2nd question? Any ideas there?

Comment: Actually never mind, I see why that happens. Because `y1` gets very very large as `x` approaches `-pi/2` from the right... and so the graph of `y2` starts looking like a line/segment.

Comment: I've enclosed in asnwer but was investigating it for a while :-)